# How to get an alert when someone logged on my PC?

Tags: windows-7, security, login, alert

I wish to send myself an mail, a message or an alert when someone logged on my machine. Is that possible to configure on my Windows 7 machine?

Answer (score 26):

Yes, you can do this.

Go to `start` > `Control Panel` > `Administrative Tools` > `Task Scheduler`

First Leftclick then Rightclick on `Task Scheduler Library` and select `Create Task...`

At Name, give it a name that is recognizable to you.

To to the tab `Triggers`

Press <kbd>New...</kbd>

At the top after Begin the task: `On a schedule` change this to: `At log on` and press <kbd>OK</kbd>

Go to the `Actions` tab and press the <kbd>New...</kbd> button.

At Action: `Start a program` change to `Send an e-mail`

Fill in all the forms, Attachment is optional. SMTP server has to be a valid smtp server. Choose the one from your ISP. If you don't know, google for `SMTP server [name of isp]`

Finally press <kbd>OK</kbd>

This will send an email everytime a user logs in, including yourself, so log out and back in to test if it works.

You may be able to use %USERNAME% in your message to show who is logged in. Given that I am on windows 8.1 I am not able to test this as the e-mail function is deprecated in this OS version.

*Important notice: This does NOT work in Windows 8 or later, nor Windows Server 2012. Sending an email or displaying a message is a deprecated function in these OS's. Displaying a msg can be done differently using `start a program` `msg` `* type message here`*

Comment: though your script can send email va say powershell.

Comment: @joojaa Yes it could, but given that this still works natively in windows 7, I didn't include that in my answer.

Comment: **I thought that Windows was supposed to be easy.** In Ubuntu just add `mail -s “Someone logged in” you@gmail.com` to the profile file.

Comment: Who said Windows was supposed to be easy? *joke*

Comment: I mean is this hard though?